# IsNan vs value != value on VS2010 for 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, double

Hi I have a function that is giving me odd behvior only on release 64 bit release builds.  32bit works in all cases and 64bit works in debug.  Anyway heres the original code, the value of value is a real number like 5 or 100 etc.:

```
static void 
Foo(char **pInOut, unsigned int key, double value)
{
if (value == -HUGE_VAL)
    return;

if (value != value)
    return;

// Does stuff that isn't happening
}
```

I was playing around and I replaced the value != value  with:

```
static void 
Foo(char **pInOut, unsigned int key, double value)
{
if (value == -HUGE_VAL)
    return;

if (_isnan(value))
    return;

// Does stuff that happens now
}
```

Now it's working.  value != value is still valid right? am I missing something...i just dont see why the old way wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a NaN, then `value!=value` will be true. But if it's not a NaN, it's not guaranteed that `value!=value` will be false.

Comment: any reason this would only affect 64bit builds?  This code has existed for years and is used constantly but never ran into a problem until now?

Comment: That's the problem with UB -- it does exactly what you expect until suddenly it doesn't. That's why you should avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

Comparing floating point values is non-intuitive.  Each floating point value contains a mere approximate representation (though some values are exact) which is affected by previous computations and handling.  Even `HUGE_VAL` might suffer from loss of precision depending on FPU mode and value handling.

Instead, compare floating point values using an [epsilon comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).  The `is_nan()` function is a precise way of inspecting the floating point value for special bits which designate it as a special representation of not-a-number.

Comment: Well, I guess the OP is aware of the precision issues of floating point values. Whereas the value of `value` may be inexact (whatever it should be), it should still equal its own value (except for NaNs). And just spamming everything with epsilons is not a good general advice. Often plain binary comparison is just enough (or even necessary), it depends entirely on the context. So this doesn't answer the question in any way. Please read the question before just crying "OMG he's binary comparing floats!".

Comment: Actually, there's no rule that requires it to equal its own value and there are reasons it might not. See, for example, this [GCC bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31008). The test for equality may have to be implemented by loading one value into a register and then comparing it to the other value in memory. The loading process may change the number's binary representation (the memory format may have different precision from the register format), causing it not to compare equal anymore.